# Reference a table in formula with table name in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, replace, excel-tables

Let's say that there is a excel sheet with a table (`Table1`) and a cell (`C1`) in which the table name is written (as text).

Can I make a formula that uses notation for using values from the table (e.g. `Table1[Column1]`), but instead of hardcoding the table name in the formula somehow reference the cell with the table name?
Or some other way to make dynamic references to tables?
Or maybe a simple find/replace or regex that can modify formulas?

Here's a simple example:

[image]

So here for example I'd like to make the formula in `F3` so it's easy to modify so that if I want to count the odd numbers in some other table (which has a column named `Column1`) I can just simply modify the table name.

*Note: This is a simplified example, in reality I have multiple complex formulas in which it would take a long time to replace the hardcoded names.*

Comment: Just replace `Table1[Column1]` with `INDIRECT(C1&"[Column1]")`, etc.

Comment: @JosWoolley Indirect() is volatile and should be avoided.

Comment: @teylyn Absolutely, though I might just add "*...if possible*" to the end of your statement. If a non-volatile set-up is not feasible, and the calculation overheads within the workbook are not likely to be an issue due to the volatility, then it is not to be dismissed out of hand as a solution. Alternative, non-VBA set-ups which employ `CHOOSE` are sometimes possible, though can be lengthy and difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((MOD(INDIRECT(C1&"["&E4&"]"),2)=1)))
```

[image]

You should take a look at `INDIRECT`: [indirect](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)

But keep in mind that your workbook might become very slow if you overuse it.